# True or false statement

Tags: real-analysis

If $ f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ is a continuous function will $f$ assume the value $ \int^{+1}_{0} f^2 \, dt $ somewhere in $[0,1]$?

Comment: Try with $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Please clarify: $f\colon\;[0,\ 1]\rightarrow [0,\ 1]$ means that $f([0,\ 1]) = [0,\ 1]?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $f(x) = c \in (0, 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to prove that such a function verifies:
$0 \leq \int^{1}_{0} f^2 \, dt  \leq 1$ ?

If so, you have for every x such as : $ 0 \leq x \leq 1 $ , $ 0 \leq f(x) \leq 1 $ => $ 0 \leq f(x)^2 \leq f(x) \leq 1 $

$f \leq g$ => $ \int_I f \leq \int_Ig$

Here I=[0,1]

=> $ 0 = \int_I 0 \leq \int_I f^2 \leq \int_I 1 = 1 $ Hence : $ 0 \leq \int_I f^2 \leq 1 $

Answer (score 1):

If $f\colon\;[0,\ 1]\rightarrow [0,\ 1] $ is surjective (and continuous) then
 1) $0 < \int\limits_{0}^{1}{f^2(x)\ dx} < 1 $ 
 2) $f$ being a continuous function on the compact set $ [0,\ 1],$ takes any value from $[0,\ 1]$ and, in particular, the value  $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{f^2(x)\ dx}.$

Comment: My $f$ is not surjective.But in case you have assumed it to be so ,it was a good answer-so an upvote.